# Weird exception in Spring

Tags: java, spring, grails

I'm getting this exception during the handling of a GET request every now and then (like once a month) in my web application. The stacktrace never touches my code, or even Grails'. I can't figure out how to reproduce it, but it always seems to happen during the first few requests.

I'm using Grails v3.3.1.

The second line of the stack trace resides at Maven coords: `org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.9.RELEASE`

Looking at Spring's source, I can't find on the referenced line (63) or anywhere in the class (`LocalVariableTPND`) where `ArrayList.add()` is called. Very odd... Any ideas?

Obviously I can't enable debugging due to it's extremely rare circumstances.

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 15
        at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:463)
        at org.springframework.core.LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.<init>(LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer.java:63)
        at org.springframework.core.DefaultParameterNameDiscoverer.<init>(DefaultParameterNameDiscoverer.java:44)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.<init>(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:54)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.<init>(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:74)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.createInvocableHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:846)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

**Edit:**
Here's the source of my handler method that handled the request. Cache-related methods are handled by: `org.grails.plugins:cache-headers:2.0.2`

```
@GrailsCompileStatic(TypeCheckingMode.SKIP)
def read() {
    Organization organization = organizationService.forId(response, params.organizationId as Long)
    if (organization == null) return

    Appeal appeal = appealService.forId(response, organization, params.appealId as Long)
    if (appeal == null) return

    MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1")
    messageDigest.update(Utils.longToBytes(appeal.version))
    String sha1Hex = new BigInteger(1, messageDigest.digest()).toString(16).padLeft(40, '0')

    withCacheHeaders {
        etag {
            sha1Hex
        }

        generate {
            // response
            response.status = SC_OK
            respond([appeal: appeal])
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit 2:**
I was able to reproduce this by accident again twice. Same stacktrace, but different indexes it was complaining about. The first time, I got 15 like before. But the second time (in the same instance of the app) was a 109.

Comment: Can you include the code where you are handling your GET request also

Comment: @billy.mccarthy Sure, but I'm not sure how this will help as the stack trace doesn't mention any of my code. See my edit.

Comment: Note that the line was *463*.

Comment: @chrylis Line 463 of `ArrayList`, but the line I'm referring to in my question is line 63 of `LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer` (the second stack trace element).

Comment: Ah, of course. This is certainly strange, and absent a sort of thread leaking/unsafe publishing that I can't image in Spring (certainly in constructors), it looks... bad.

Comment: Unrelated to your question but just FYI... Instead of `@GrailsCompileStatic(TypeCheckingMode.SKIP)` you can do `@CompileDynamic`.  I think the latter is more expressive and evokes fewer questions.